# How to fill numpy array during it's creation by ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create array 5x5, which looks like:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I want to do it with numpy using `ndarray`, I write `np.ndarray((5, 5))` and then fill it as I need, but the answer is can I fill it during creation with this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) (to repeat an array specified number of times):

```
np.tile(np.arange(5), (5,1))
```

---

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```